# .NET Console app 80040154 Class not registered after copied to different machine

Tags: .net, vb.net, console

First time creating a Console App (.NET Framework) using Visual Studio 2019. I am using a 3rd party 64-bit COM DLL that I added to my project using "Add Reference". I built the project and copied both the DLL and the .exe (from Release folder) to another 64-bit Windows machine and tried to run it from the command line. When I do, I get the error: Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered.

From an administrator command prompt I ran: regsvr32 dllfile.dll and it said registered successfully, but the error persists.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Regasm.exe (Assembly Registration Tool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool)

Comment: I get: error RA0000: Failed to load 'dllfile.dll' because it is not a valid .NET assembly. Tried regasm.exe from both Framework and Framework64 folders.